# Webpack create JSON map file with dynamic modules

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a project where I use [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) in conjunction with Webpack's dynamic imports.

What I have is that the initial javascript file is as small as possible and then for each page, I load the relevant javascript code:

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const moduleName = document.body.dataset.route;
  if (!moduleName) return;

  const chunkName = moduleName.replace('.', '/');
  import(`@pages/${chunkName}.js`)
    .catch((e) => {console.error(e);});
});
```

This is a great approach as each page gets its own minimal JS file.

The only issue is that we wait until the page has fully loaded before we fetch the page's javascript which makes initial page loads feel slightly slow. Ideally, I would love to preload the assets for the page when the page loads.

I thought that maybe adding a `link rel=preload` would solve this issue but the thing is that I do not know which chunks I need to preload on each page. This is logic that only Weboack knows.

My `webpack.config.js` file looks like:

```js
output: {
  chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]',
},
```

So basically each chunk is put in the `js/chunks` directory and its name is `0.js, 1.js, 2.js` etc.

I would love to maybe somehow generate an additional `json` file where webpack can build a map for me. It would basically look like this (chunk key: modules that are within it):

```js
{
  0: ['@pages/tips/index.js', '@pages/tips/show.js'],
  1: ['@pages/destinations/index.js', '@pages/tips/show.js'],
}
```

Then, I would read the file on each page and dynamically create the `link rel=preload`. For example, say I render the `tips/show` page now, I would scan the file above for each key that contains the `@pages/tips/show.js` and render a `link rel=preload` for each file (`0.js` and `1.js` file in this case).

I'm using [Webpack Commons Chunk](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) plugin to extract the same vendors and modules to their own chunk file.

Is doing such a thing is even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Where these files in the array comes from? (why chunk 0 has 2 files)?

Comment: @felixmosh Hey. It seems like I forgot to mention that I'm using webpack chunk plugin that exports common chunks into their own files (which causes `tips/show` to appear in 2 chunks). The files in the array are the files that the chunk contains. Usually, if you open the chunk files, you can see a comment above each section in the file that tells you what file this chunk refers to

Answer (score 0):

Webpack has something that is called `stats` that contains a-lot of info regarding the compilation.

It also contains the separation of chunks.

You can checkout what [react-loadable webpack plugin](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable/blob/master/src/webpack.js) does in order to generate similar task.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
You will need to write a webpack plugin that hooks on `emit` phase and then you will have an access to the `compilation` object that has all the data.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll take a look at that later this week and see if it gives me what I need. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, how do I access the `stats` object? A small snippet would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: call webpack() from node, it will return callback(err,stat);